# how to use java script code for two or more buttons

Tags: javascript, css

```
var element = document.getElementById('text');
document.getElementById("wedding").onclick = function(){
  element.style.position = "absolute";
  element.style.left = '-450px';
  element.style.top = '-260px';
  element.style.zoom = 0.8;
  element.style.MozTransform = 'scale(0.8)';
  element.style.WebkitTransform = 'scale(0.8)';
}
```

i need to use above code for two buttons. so i change this code like below, but its not working.
 how can i do that.

```
var element = document.getElementById('text');
document.getElementById("wedding divorce").onclick = function(){
   element.style.position = "absolute";
   element.style.left = '-450px';
   element.style.top = '-260px';
   element.style.zoom = 0.8;
   element.style.MozTransform = 'scale(0.8)';
   element.style.WebkitTransform = 'scale(0.8)';
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between the two examples?

Comment: @FelixKling Bad phrased question , but I think he wants to run same func for different elements.

Comment: @FelixKling I was wondering if it was just me!

Comment: i did some mistake. i need to animate text when click #wedding or #Divorce.

Comment: @user2607456 that's my sample does.

Comment: i need to animate #text when click #wedding or #Divorce. but your code there's no #text. can you add #text to this code.

Comment: document.getElementById("wedding divorce").onclick = function(){, i tried like this , but its not worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to run the same function for different elements call the function name and not the function imploementation itself :

```
document.getElementById("wedding").onclick = lalala;

document.getElementById("divorce").onclick = lalala;

//inside you can use `this` ( notice we didnt pass [this] , it is done automatically)

function lalala()
{
     this.style.position = "absolute";
     this.style.left = '-450px';
     this.style.top = '-260px';
     this.style.zoom = 0.8;
     this.style.MozTransform = 'scale(0.8)';
     this.style.WebkitTransform = 'scale(0.8)';

}
```

**After OP clarification**

```
var e=document.getElementById("text") 

document.getElementById("wedding").onclick =function (){ lalala(e) };

document.getElementById("divorce").onclick =function (){ lalala(e) };




function lalala(elm)
{
     elm.style.position = "absolute";
     elm.style.left = '-450px';
     elm.style.top = '-260px';
     elm.style.zoom = 0.8;
     elm.style.MozTransform = 'scale(0.8)';
     elm.style.WebkitTransform = 'scale(0.8)';

}
```

Comment: It is probably better to use CSS classes and put the style into a CSS file. This will enable one to a) easily change the CSS by not having to modify the Javascript and b) Have multiple styles say for example one with a larger font for people with visual impairments

Comment: @EdHeal Agree but the OP says : _so i change this code like below, but its not working. how can i do that?_ I assume he wants to know why his code is not working rather than finding another way of doing it.

Comment: @RoylNamir - I just made it as a comment as he person who wrote the OP might have not thought about it.

Comment: @EdHeal As I said , I agree.

Comment: i did some mistake. i need to animate #text when click #wedding or #Divorce. but your code there's no #text. can you add #text to this code.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("btn1").onclick = apply_style();

function apply_style(){
document.getElementById("my_div").className="my_css_class";
}

In your css:

.my_css_class{
     position = "absolute";
     left = '-450px';
     top = '-260px';
     transform: scale(0.8);
     -ms-transform: scale(0.8); /* IE 9 */
     -webkit-transform: scale(0.8); /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```